# Mouse Event pageX pageY Element Calibration

Tags: javascript, events, google-chrome, alignment

My Code :

```
var x = window.event.pageX + document.body.scrollLeft;
var y = window.event.pageY + document.body.scrollTop ;
$(document.body).append("<div id='loadeditlang'></div>");
$("#loadeditlang").css({position:'absolute',  top:y, left:x});
```

All Works Fine into Opera but Chrome have problem: when i have scrolling top align gets too much Y pixels...

Comment: on which event you doing this? and what you want to achieve by this?

Comment: when i click edit icon this div element is appended into X and Y position. and this is mouseEvent

Comment: I create a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/KsLtK/. is this you want?

Comment: i open console log and chrome scrollTop Gives 100 and Opera gives 79... is that chrome bug?

Comment: I don't think so, It depends on amount of scroll in document. means pixel of top hidden document.